# Gunicorn error: unrecognized arguments: run:app (using waitress and nginx)

Tags: nginx, flask, waitress

I am using an AWS ubuntu machine to run a Flask Blueprints application. I have been able to run in development mode where my service file has an ExecStart like this:
`ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/environments/venv_wsh06api/bin/gunicorn -w 3 -b 0.0.0.0:8001  run:app`

But now I want to run using waitress. I have tried every iteration I can think of:
`gunicorn waitress -w 3 -b 0.0.0.0:8080 run:app`

and each is giving some version of “gunicorn: error: unrecognized arguments: run:app”. It’s always last argument where I am telling what app to run that is being called out as the error.

I have seen some very elaborate run.py files but none seem to apply to me. I know there are a few other posts and even a [Medium article](https://medium.com/@erlangen-sheppy/flask-standalone-to-wsgi-app-d018b2740020) that closely address my needs. I’ve parsed through them in detail alternating things and still not getting anywhere.

Any advice greatly appreciated. Even a suggestion where to look would be wonderful. Thanks.

wsh06dev03.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn instance to serve wsh06api3.service in venv_wsh06api.
After=network.target

[Service]
User=ubuntu
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/applications/whatSticks06api
Environment="PATH=/home/ubuntu/environments/venv_wsh06api/bin"
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/environments/venv_wsh06api/bin/gunicorn waitress -w 3 -b 0.0.0.0:8080 run:app

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

run.py

```
from app_package import create_app
from waitress import serve

app = create_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    serve(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

**init**.py

```
from flask import Flask
from wsh_config import ConfigDev, ConfigProd
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
import os

config_object = ConfigDev()

logs_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'logs')

if not os.path.exists(logs_dir):
    os.makedirs(logs_dir)

#Setting up Logger


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config_object)

    from app_package.scheduler.routes import sched_route
    
    app.register_blueprint(sched_route)
    
    return app
```

Comment: Gunicorn and Waitress are both WSGI Servers, you only need to serve you app with one. If you want to use waitress remove your call to Gunicorn.

Comment: `ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/environments/venv_wsh06api/bin/waitress-serve --call 'run:app'` worked... thank you!!!

Comment: To be clear I other issues with missing arguments in Flask(), but the waitress/gunicorn problem is solved as @PGHE said